# magento2: PHP Extension sockets rediness check error

Tags: installation, magento2.3.4, readiness-check

How to fix **PHP Extension sockets** readiness check error in magento 2.3.4.

[image]

Comment: please check my answer

Answer (score 1):

Open php.ini file.

Find sockets and remove the comment in the first line.

Replace

from:

> ;extension=sockets

To:

> extension=sockets

Save the file then restart your apache server and try again.

**Hope this will help you!!**

Answer (score 0):

***Solution***

```
change ;extension=sockets to extension=sockets over php.ini
```

Answer (score 0):

I am experiencing the same issue. As the hosting provider is not willing to enable the extension sockets, is there a workaround to disable this extension within Magento and continue with the set-up?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I changed the following in the file setup/src/Magento/Setup/Model/PhpReadinessCheck.php:

$missing = array_values(array_diff($required, $current));
into
$missing = array_values(array_diff($current, $current));

This allows to pass the php extensions check, but can anybody indicate whether this action will cause any harm? To which extent is the PHP Extension Sockets essential for running Magento?